# How to unset the objects from objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

This is my document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaa152feee5f2e60dff06f"),
    "name" : "ABC",
    "hobbies" : {
        "cricket" : {
            "hobbyName" : "cricket"
        },
        "football" : {
            "hobbyName" : "football"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaa196feee5f2e60dff070"),
    "name" : "D",
    "hobbies" : {
        "Tennis" : {
            "hobbyName" : "Tennis"
        },
        "Volleyball" : {
            "hobbyName" : "Volleyball"
        },
        "basketball" : {
            "hobbyName" : "basketball"
        }
    }
}

var find = [ "Tennis", "football"];
```

Above my document under `hobbies` object suppose Tennis & football value is there , I want to unset that particular object

My code:

```
var find = [ "Tennis", "football"];
db.Hobbies.find({})
.forEach(function(doc){
    var _id = doc._id;
    for(let i=0;i<find.length;i++){ 
    let remove  = find[i];
    let concate = "hobbies." + remove;
    let text = '"'+concate+'"';
        db.Hobbies.update(
            {'_id': _id},
            {$unset: { text : {_id: remove} }} 
        )
    }
})
```

My expected output is:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaa152feee5f2e60dff06f"),
    "name" : "ABC",
    "hobbies" : {
        "cricket" : {
            "hobbyName" : "cricket"
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ccaa196feee5f2e60dff070"),
    "name" : "D",
    "hobbies" : {
        "Volleyball" : {
            "hobbyName" : "Volleyball"
        },
        "basketball" : {
            "hobbyName" : "basketball"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete ; use delete operator

Comment: Can u please update my code

Comment: I am new to the mongodb, please anyone update my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read a little bit about the [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator.
Basically you need to specify the Field name to unset.
Correct snippet should look like this:

```
db.Hobbies.update(
    {'_id': _id},
    {$unset: { "hobbies.Tennis": "", "hobbies.footbal": ""}, 
)
```

also if you want to remove all tennis and football hobbies:

```
db.Hobbies.update(
    {},
    {$unset: { "hobbies.Tennis": "", "hobbies.footbal": ""}, 
    {multi: true}
)
```

EDIT: a dynamic way.

```
let find = [ "Tennis", "football"];
db.Hobbies.find({})
    .forEach(function(doc){
       var _id = doc._id;
       let unset_obj = {};
       for(let i=0; i < find.length; i++){ 
            let key = `hobbies.${find[i]}`;
            unset_obj[key] = "";
        }
        db.Hobbies.update(
            {'_id': _id},
            {$unset: unset_obj} 
        )
    }
})
```

dynamic way all documents:

```
let find = [ "Tennis", "football"];
var _id = doc._id;
let unset_obj = {};
for(let i=0; i < find.length; i++){ 
    let key = `hobbies.${find[i]}`;
    unset_obj[key] = "";
}
db.Hobbies.update(
            {},
            {$unset: unset_obj},
            {multi: true}
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: Actually I want to do like var find array what are the values is there , I want to Unset those values, ur giving static values, can u please update ur code like var find how we can use

Comment: it's working fine but i didn't get like this information `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 2, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 2 })`

Comment: use [findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) instead of update if u want to get the new document. add the new:true to the options but then you only do one at a time.

Comment: I am getting like this `Script executed successfully, but there is no result to show.`

Comment: While multiple `unset` , we can't get those modified information ?

Comment: ur edited answer is working fine, but i am having huge number of records, so it's taking to much to load

Comment: I think we have to avoid the for loop `.forEach(function(doc){`, is there any way to avoid for loop ?

Comment: yes ofcourse, the forEach is just to do it for a single document so you need its id, you can do it in one call otherwise, in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop on db.Hobbies.find({}). try direct:

```
    var find = [ "Tennis", "football"];
    for(let i=0;i<find.length;i++){ 
    let remove  = find[i];
    let concate = "hobbies." + remove;
    console.log(concate)
        db.Hobbies.update({},{$unset:{concate : 1}},{multi : true} 
        )
    }
```

this will unset all the documents and will also skip a loop and query

Comment: try updated code and let me know what you get in concate

Comment: console.log(concate)// `hobbies.Tennis hobbies.football`

Comment: Still not `unset` the values